# Use stringstream and ifstream to compare user input to words in a file

Tags: c++, file, fstream, ifstream, istringstream

I am writing a program to compare a user inputted sentence to words in a file. I want the program to tell me if any of the words in the sentence are found in the file.

I am using getline to get a user inputted sentence and then I am using a istringstream to chop the sentence into words and compare each individual word to every word in the file. My approach is to use a while loop to iterate through every word in the file and compare the current word in the user inputted sentence to the current word in the file. If the current file word is the same as the current sentence word then I'll set a bool to true, if not then I want to skip to the next word in the file and compare the sentence word to the next file word.

I'm not sure how to get both the istringstream and ifstream to jump to the next word in my while loop. How can I iterate to the next word?

EDIT: I need to do this without using a vector, array, etc. My initial approach was to use a vector but that's not allowed.

```
int main() {
    string sentence;
    string fileWord;

    cout << "Input your sentence : " << endl;
    getline(cin, sentence);

    istringstream iss(sentence);
    string sentenceWord;

    ifstream adjectiveFile;
    adjectiveFile.open("/project1.cpp/words/adjectives");

    while(iss >> sentenceWord && adjectiveFile >> fileWord) {
        if (sentenceWord == fileWord) {
            cout << "The word " << sentenceWord << " is in the file" << endl;
            bool adjectiveInSent = true;
        } else {

        }
    }

    adjectiveFile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't do it like that. Read the whole file into a std::set, and then look up  the words you extract from the stringstream in the set.

Comment: What is `bool adjectiveInSent = true;` supposed to do?

Comment: Later on in the program I have to check if the user inputted sentence is structured a certain way i.e. noun, verb, noun, etc.

Comment: @NickKinlen There's no _laterz_ with scope local variables.

Comment: @NickKinlen _"I need to do this without using a vector, array, etc. My initial approach was to use a vector but that's not allowed."_ WTF?? One can make silly restrictions. You have to use nested loops that read from the `istringstream` and reset it (`clear()`,`seek(0)`) multiple times then or such. Demand your money back from your incompetent teacher.

Comment: If you can't use containers, you need a nested while loop. Outer loop iterates over words in `adjectiveFile`, inner loop over `iss`. Before inner loop starts, call `iss.seek(0)` every time.

Comment: @zett42 Yeah, that's what I'm referring to in my previous comment. That sounds extremely inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

You could do following:

a ) store the words from file in a stl container say
 `std::set<std::string>`

b) Read the user inputs and extract it in using your `std::istringstream`
   Now for each words extract simple search that in map formed in a) using `find` method of the container.

Comment: What should be the map key?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yeah, I think `std::set` should just be fine.

Comment: Hmm, the other way round??

Answer (score 0):

An acceptable c++ solution should look like this:

```
int main() {
    string sentence;

    cout << "Input your sentence : " << endl;
    getline(cin, sentence);

    istringstream iss(sentence);
    std::set<string> lookUpWords;
    std::string word;
    while(iss >> word) {
        if(lookUpWords.find(word) != lookUpWords.end()) {
            lookUpWords.insert(word);
        }
    }

    ifstream adjectiveFile("/project1.cpp/words/adjectives");

    string fileWord;
    while(adjectiveFile >> fileWord) {

        if (lookUpWords.find(fileWord) != lookUpWords.end()) {
            cout << "The word " << sentenceWord << " is in the file" << endl;
        }
    }

    adjectiveFile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

---

As for your edit regarding restrictions you can do that without `std::istringstream` (as long that's not another silly restriction you have to use it):

```
int main() {
    string sentence;

    cout << "Input your sentence : " << endl;
    getline(cin, sentence);

    ifstream adjectiveFile("/project1.cpp/words/adjectives");

    string fileWord;
    while(adjectiveFile >> fileWord) {

        if (sentence.find(fileWord) != std::string::npos) {
            cout << "The word " << sentenceWord << " is in the file" << endl;
        }
    }

    adjectiveFile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The problem is I can't use sets, arrays, vectors, any libraries, etc.

Comment: @NickKinlen Read my comment regarding your edit. That's just a very silly restriction.

Comment: @NickKinlen Provided an alternate solution.

Comment: `sentence.find()` won't work correctly for compound words though.

Comment: @zett42 Mind to elaborate? What do you mean by _compound words_? Were these in question actually?

Comment: Example: word "green" in adjectives file will incorrectly match word "evergreen" in sentence.

Comment: @zett42 Yeah, I just realized now what you mean. Well, the requirements are still unclear IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using only streams. As commenters noted, it is not very efficient, but teachers are teachers and assignments are assignments. ;-)

The algorithm works correctly for compound words. It won't match "fip" with "fipfop" like a simple `string.find()` would do.

I'm using an `istringstream` for `adjectiveFile` only for easier testing. You can replace it by `ifstream` of course.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    istringstream iss("bar fam fop fip");
    istringstream adjectiveFile("foo bar baz fup fam fiz fipfop");

    string fileWord, sentenceWord;
    while( adjectiveFile >> fileWord ) {
        iss.clear();    // clear EOF
        iss.seekg( 0 ); // start from beginning
        while( iss >> sentenceWord ) { 
            if (sentenceWord == fileWord) {
                cout << "The word " << sentenceWord << " is in the file" << endl;
            } 
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3183c0186a602449).

**Output:**

```
The word bar is in the file
The word fam is in the file
```